# NSLinkAttributeName highlight color bug for non-English word support

Tags: ios7, uitextview

when I want to add link detect for @username,  it is fine, but when the username is not English word, then when I tap on it, the hight light only cover on @

now, I fix it like this:
add a color attribute to @, and then add a link attribute to username.

Did anyone have better solution.

[image]

Comment: How did you track the `@zzz` words to add them a `NSLinkAttributeName`?

Comment: I use regexp  (@\[\\w\\u4e00-\\u9fa5]+) 

    NSRange   searchedRange = NSMakeRange(0, text.length);
    NSString *pattern = @"(@\[\\w\\u4e00-\\u9fa5]+|http://[^ \\r\\n\\)）]+|#[^#]+#|)";
    
    NSError  *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
    NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:text options:0 range: searchedRange];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches) {
        NSString* matchText = [text substringWithRange:[match range]];

Comment: So your question may be about on the regex part?

Comment: no, my question is the hightlight region when I tap,  when I detect @名字, the hightlight will only cover @,  and there is no hightlight color covering for 名字

Comment: Does `名字` have also the `NSLinkAttributeName`?

Comment: yes. I add the NSLinkAttributeName to entire @名字